# RPAD with non constant parameter

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to "compare" strings like  and  together in bigquery so I'm looking at doing

```
SELECT
...
WHERE
text1 != RPAD(text2, LENGTH(text1), SUBSTR(text2, 1, 1))
```

unfortunately I get the error
`Third argument must be const, non-null and of type string`

I really want to check that **text1 = text2 + some repeated character**, not just a substring

I do not want to trim text1 to compare it to text2 (unless I could check if the remainder of text1 is the repeated sequence of the 1st character in text2).

What are the solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is for BigQuery Standtard SQL

```
WHERE text1 != CONCAT(text2, REPEAT(SUBSTR(text1, LENGTH(text2), 1), LENGTH(text1) - LENGTH(text2)))
```

You can test it with below dummy example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '' text1, '' text2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', ''
)
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE text1 != CONCAT(text2, REPEAT(SUBSTR(text1, LENGTH(text2), 1), LENGTH(text1) - LENGTH(text2)))
```

result is

```
Row text1       text2    
1   1
```

as you can see the first row was filtered out because of `repeated character`

Comment: works! I was using legacy sql, it didn't have "repeat()"

Comment: consider voting up the answer :o) - meantime do you still need it in legacy or standard will work for yo  - it is highly recommended to migrate to standard sql though

Comment: yeah I was waiting for something I couldn't do with legacy to stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `like`?

```
where text2 like concat(text1, '%')
```

Comment: thanks but I want to specifically check that the reminder is a REPEATED character, let me edit the question to be more specific